# Conditions for a minimal derived $A_\infty$-algebra to be bounded

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras, projective-resolution

I was looking for some examples of derived $A_\infty$-algebras (or $dA_\infty$-algebras) in the original reference by Sagave, [DG-algebras and derived A-infinity algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.4499), where some examples obtained as minimal models are given. I have noticed that all the examples (5.1 and 5.3) are bounded in the sense that $m_{ij}$ vanishes for $i+j$ large enough.

I was wondering if there is some sufficient condition on the dga that we are resolving to ensure that the minimal $dA_\infty$-algebra is bounded in that sense.

Following the proof of existence of minimal models (Theorem 1.1), which is used to compute the examples, the first step is finding a projective resolution by a bidga $B$ (that is in particular a $dA_\infty$-algebra with $m_{ij}=0$ for $i+j\geq 3$). This is done in Theorem 3.4. Then, $B$ is replaced by the homology $E=H_*(B,m_{01})$ with respect to the differential $m_{01}$ to ensure minimality. This is done in Proposition 4.7. In this proposition, the $dA_\infty$-structure is defined inductively from a selection homomorphism $f_{01}:E\to B$ whose existence is guaranteed by projectivity of $E$.

The $dA_\infty$-structures in the examples are always bounded "because of degree reasons", which I understand that it is because $H_*(B,m_{01})$ is bounded in the examples. So maybe, the question can be reduced to: what are some conditions on a dga that ensure that the projective resolution given by Theorem 3.4 has a bounded homology?

I am not well-versed in the techniques used in Theorem 3.4 so I would have a very hard time just trying to learn the things needed to understand the proof.

Edit: I'll give an overview of what is done in the proof of Theorem 3.4. Given a dga $A$, it is regarded as a bidga concentrated in horizontal degree $0$. Then take the constant simplicial chain complex (bicomplex?) $\Gamma(A)_n=\oplus_{[n]\twoheadrightarrow [p]}A_{p*}$. It is shown by previous results that the cofibrant replacement $\Gamma(A)^{cof}$ has projective vertical homology. Finally, the chain complex functor is applied and $C(\Gamma(A)^{cof})$ is the desired projective resolution.